# How can I transfer a detail exception message within gRPC's responseObserver.onError()

Tags: grpc, grpc-java

I'm trying to transfer a detail message that describe the exception with gRPC. I've learned that I should use responseObserver.onError to transfer it, and gRPC offer Metadata to do it, but I still don't know where to put it because i can't create a Metadata, all the constructor of Metadata is not public.

```
static class GrpcTestService extends GrpcTestGrpc.GrpcTestImplBase {

        @Override
        public void sayHello(HelloRequest req, StreamObserver<HelloResponse> responseObserver) {
            try {
                HelloResponse reply = HelloResponse.newBuilder().setMessage("got it ! " + req.getName()).build();
                throw new RuntimeException("I'm an exception!!!");
//                responseObserver.onNext(reply);
//                responseObserver.onCompleted();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                responseObserver.onError(new StatusRuntimeException(Status.ABORTED, new Metadata("metadata exception".getBytes())));
            }
        }
    }
```

As above, I can't create an Metadata by 'new Metadata("xxxx")', so how can I wrap my special message within responseObserver.onError?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To send a detailed message, attach it to a `Status` with `withDescription`:

```
Status.ABORTED.withDescription("The detailed reason")
```

The description is useful for developers to debug the system. It is not intended for machine consumption.

The constructor for `Metadata` is public, but has no arguments. You create it with `new Metadata()` and then can modify it with things like `put(Key<T> key, T value)`. Metadata is useful for sending machine-understandable error details.